# Sqlite query with order by is not working?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Select Query is not working with order by :

i have this  QuestionTable , there in no primary key and for particular participant  dbpointer is unique, for other oparticipant it will repeat

[image]
  i want  to fetch 5 row  at at time for particular participantid,  so dbpointer (column name ) should be (1,2,3,4,5) but it is coming (1,10, 2, 3, 4)

[image]

Pleaes help me ....  Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your query here, what you exactly querying?

Comment: SELECT * FROM QuestionTable  WHERE particapantuhId='ggg_1' AND  dbpointer >0 ORDER BY  dbpointer   LIMIT 5

Comment: Looks like the `dbpointer` is of type `TEXT` in which case the ordering seems to be right.

Comment: "order by rowid" for me this way its working

Comment: ya try with rowid, and see if its working or not

Comment: Try to add order direction, ASC or DESC like this SELECT * FROM QuestionTable WHERE particapantuhId='ggg_1' AND dbpointer >0 ORDER BY dbpointer ASC LIMIT 5

Comment: `"10" < "2"` hmmm seems like a `true` to me ... on the other hand `10 < 2` is `false`

Comment: By mistake i made it TEXT , after changing to INTEGER its working

Comment: hmm grt , so have you done it completely trupti?

Comment: yes now its working perfectly @ Pratik

Comment: @Trupti yup grt it is...

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of dbpointer to a numeric type, it seems to me that that the problem, its ordering your dbpointer column by TEXT not by NUMBER.